# How to add the height of one element to the top margin of another element using JQuery

Tags: jquery, header, margin, nav, parseint

I have a nav and a header using html5. The nav is fixed to the top of the page. It's height is not explicitly defined in the css (its created through font sizes, padding, etc.).

I am adding a header to go underneath the nav. I need to find a way to add a margin to the top of the header so that the header is 100% underneath (no overshadowing, no run-ins) the nav. Adding the nav's height as the margin would do this, but in addition to that, i need to **add on** (addition) the nav's height to the margin **that will already be defined in the css**. I used this code to no avail.

*#main=nav

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("header").css("margin-top", parseInt($(this)[0].css("margin-top") + $("#main")[0].outerHeight) + "px");
});
</script>
```

Please Help!

Comment: Just to be clear... You want the header to be _touching but not overlapping_ the nav, is that correct?

Comment: No... completely detached, i want to add the height of the nav to the height of the margin already indicated.

Comment: Why don't you use the CSS `top` property? For example: `$("header").css("top", $("#main")[0].outerHeight + "px");` (This would leave the `margin-top` property alone to whatever it was set in CSS.)

Comment: If i use "top" this wouldn't affect the positioning (fixed, absolute, etc.) would it?

Answer (score 2):

I got it. I used an iteration of ilya's idea. I added a container around everything that wasn't the nav and added top padding that was the height of the nav. I of course accomplished this through jQuery:

```
$("#container").css("padding-top", $("#main").outerHeight() + "px" );
```

It works wonderfully. Thank you!